# Let $D,E,F$ be (respectively) the projections of $O$ on $BC,CA,AB$. Prove that $\cot{\angle ADB} + \cot{\angle BEC} + \cot{\angle CFA} =0$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

Let $O$ be an arbitrary point located inside the triangle $ABC$. Let $D, E, F$ be (respectively) the projections of $O$ on $BC, CA, AB$. Prove that $$\cot{\measuredangle ADB} + \cot{\measuredangle BEC} + \cot{\measuredangle CFA} =0$$

Comment: Are $AD, BF, CG$ all medians?

Comment: @DavidQuinn: The problem statement implies that $O$ is an *arbitrary* point in the triangle, so those line segments are not necessarily medians. In fact, in the diagram the three segments are not quite concurrent, so they cannot all be medians. That is a poorly done diagram, however. My experiments in Geogebra show that the problem statement is true for arbitrary $O$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification as the diagram was misleading. I look forward to seeing your proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice question. I am assuming all the angles are directed. (Directed angles modulo $180^\circ$ are sufficient here, since $\cot$ is periodic with period $180^\circ$.)

We direct our three sidelines $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$. All distances along these lines will thus be understood to mean directed distances. Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be the feet of the altitudes of triangle $ABC$ emanating from $A$, $B$, $C$. Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be the midpoints of the segments $BC$, $CA$, $AB$.

**1.** Pythagoras in the right-angled triangles $ODB$ and $ODC$ yields $BO^2 = BD^2 + OD^2$ and $CO^2 = CD^2 + OD^2$. Subtracting these two equalities yields $BO^2 - CO^2 = \left(BD^2 + OD^2\right) - \left(CD^2 + OD^2\right) = BD^2 - CD^2$. Similarly, $CO^2 - AO^2 = CE^2 - AE^2$ and $AO^2 - BO^2 = AF^2 - BF^2$. Summing the last three equalities, we obtain

$\left(BO^2 - CO^2\right) + \left(CO^2 - AO^2\right) + \left(AO^2 - BO^2\right) = \left(BD^2 - CD^2\right) + \left(CE^2 - AE^2\right) + \left(AF^2 - BF^2\right)$.

The left hand side of this equality simplifies to $0$, and so it becomes

**(1)** $0 = \left(BD^2 - CD^2\right) + \left(CE^2 - AE^2\right) + \left(AF^2 - BF^2\right)$.

This is nothing new so far (just a well-known equality, I think due to Carnot, which can be regarded as an additive analogue of Ceva's theorem, or at least a direction of it).

**2.** Since $U$ is the midpoint of $BC$, we have $BU = - CU$ (remember that our lengths are directed), so that $BU + CU = 0$. Now, adding the equalities $BD = BU + UD$ and $CD = CU + UD$, we obtain $BD + CD = \left(BU + UD\right) + \left(CU + UD\right) = \underbrace{BU + CU}_{=0} + 2 \cdot UD = 2 \cdot UD$. Now,

$BD^2 - CD^2 = \underbrace{\left(BD + CD\right)}_{=2 \cdot UD} \underbrace{\left(BD - CD\right)}_{= BC} = 2 \cdot UD \cdot BC$.

Similarly, $CE^2 - AE^2 = 2 \cdot VE \cdot CA$ and $AF^2 - BF^2 = 2 \cdot WF \cdot AB$. Using the last three equalities, we can rewrite **(1)** as

$0 = 2 \cdot UD \cdot BC + 2 \cdot VE \cdot CA + 2 \cdot WF \cdot AB$.

Dividing this by $2$, we obtain

**(2)** $0 = UD \cdot BC + VE \cdot CA + WF \cdot AB$.

**3.** Let $H$ be the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$. Then, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are the feet of the perpendiculars from $H$ to $BC$, $CA$, $AB$. Thus, we can apply **(2)** to $H$, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ instead of $O$, $D$, $E$ and $F$, respectively. We thus obtain

$0 = UX \cdot BC + VY \cdot CA + WZ \cdot AB$.

Subtracting this equality from **(2)**, we obtain

$0 = \left(UD \cdot BC + VE \cdot CA + WF \cdot AB\right) - \left(UX \cdot BC + VY \cdot CA + WZ \cdot AB\right)$

$= \underbrace{\left(UD - UX\right)}_{= XD} \cdot BC + \underbrace{\left(VE - VY\right)}_{= YE} \cdot CA + \underbrace{\left(WF - WZ\right)}_{= ZF} \cdot AB$

**(3)** $= XD \cdot BC + YE \cdot CA + ZF \cdot AB$.

**4.** Let us direct the line $AX$ in such a way that rotating a positive-length vector on the line $BC$ by $90^\circ$ clockwise produces a positive-length vector on the line $AX$. Let us direct the lines $BY$ and $CZ$ similarly. Let $\Delta$ be the signed area of triangle $ABC$. Recall that the area of a triangle equals half times an altitude times the corresponding sidelength. Hence, $\Delta = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot AX \cdot BC = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot BY \cdot CA = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot CZ \cdot AB$. (This is a honest equality, not just an equality that holds up to sign; and the reason for this is how we directed the lines $AX$, $BY$ and $CZ$.) From $\Delta = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot AX \cdot BC$, we obtain $BC = \dfrac{2 \Delta}{AX}$. Similarly, $CA = \dfrac{2 \Delta}{BY}$ and $AB = \dfrac{2 \Delta}{CZ}$. Using the last three equalities, we can rewrite **(3)** as

$0 = XD \cdot \dfrac{2 \Delta}{AX} + YE \cdot \dfrac{2 \Delta}{BY} + ZF \cdot \dfrac{2 \Delta}{CZ}$.

Dividing this equality by $2 \Delta$ and simplifying, we obtain

**(4)** $0 = \dfrac{XD}{AX} + \dfrac{YE}{BY} + \dfrac{ZF}{CZ}$.

Now, the right-angled triangle $AXD$ yields $\dfrac{XD}{AX} = \cot \measuredangle ADX = \cot \measuredangle ADB$. (We are using the interplay between directed lengths and directed angles here -- again, the way how we directed the line $AX$ is important here.) Similarly, $\dfrac{YE}{BY} = \cot \measuredangle BEC$ and $\dfrac{ZF}{CZ} = \cot \measuredangle CFA$. Using the last three equalities, we can rewrite **(4)** as

$0 = \cot \measuredangle ADB + \cot \measuredangle BEC + \cot \measuredangle CFA$.

Done!

Comment: Your equation (1) is indeed [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Carnot.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\measuredangle ADB=\alpha$ and $AD', BE'$ be altitudes. Take $BD'=x$, $DD'=y$, $CD=z$. Assume $x+y+z=a$, (if $a=x+z-y$, we can follow similarly).

If $h_a$ is the altitude of $\triangle ABC$ on $BC$, we know that $2h_a (\cot B +\cot C)=a$. Using it on $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$ gives:

$$\frac{\cot B +\cot\alpha}{\cot C-\cot\alpha}=\frac{BD}{CD}$$

On simplifying, we have: $$\frac{BD\cot C - CD\cot B}{a}=\cot\alpha$$

Thus, all we need to prove is:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}BDbc\cot C - CDbc\cot B=0$$
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}BDb\cos C - CDc\cos B=0$$
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+y)(z+y) - xz=ay=0$$

This follows easily from Carnot's theorem:
$$0=\sum_{cyc} (BD^2-CD^2)-(BD'^2-CD'^2)=(x+y)^2-x^2+(y+z)^2-z^2=2ay$$

Hence, we showed that $\sum_{cyc} ay=0$, and we are done. Note that if say $AC= CE'+AE-EE'$, then $AC\cdot EE'$, would have a negative sign, which is why the cyclic sum works.